# Importing csv to SharePoint list with Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, sharepoint-2010

I want to import data from a CSV to a SharePoint list, all I'm getting from my script is blank rows. Here is my code:

```
# CSV path/File name
$contents = Import-Csv ".\Input.csv"

# Web URL
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://Zaxiyn/" 

# SPList name
$list = $web.Lists["Technical Profile List"] 


# Iterate for each list column

foreach ($row in $csv) {
    $item = $list.Items.Add();
    $item["Computer"] = $row.Computer;
    $item["ItemOrder"] = $row.ItemOrder;
    $item["Category"] = $row.Category;
    $item["ItemName"] = $row.ItemName;
    $item["ItemValue"] = $row.ItemValue;
    $item.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're referring to a variable that doesn't exist. The csv file content is saved in  $contents and your foreach statement uses $csv, try this:

```
foreach ($row in $contents) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I can't believe I missed that! If I had multiple csv's in a specific folder, how would I iterate through them all to add to the SharePoint list? my idea was to use: ls *.csv | $file in Get-Children ".\csvfiles\" { ... }

Comment: ls *.csv | foreach-object{ $contents = import-csv $_.fullname; foreach ($row in $contents) ... }

Comment: Consider marking my trad as the answer if it resolved your issue